# Login (django project)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm having problems with django's user accounts/login

I can't go to link  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/authenticate/login/'

and this is my errors:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /authenticate/login/

This is the main URL file of the project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('article.urls')),
    path('authenticate/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

and this is my app's url:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('Matin/', views.matin, name='Matin'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Do I have to write a view too or does it use a Django view?

this is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import PostArticle
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


 def matin(requsts):
    postarticle = PostArticle.objects.all()
    context = {'postarticle': postarticle}
    return render(requsts, 'article/matin.html', context)


def register(requsts):
    if requsts.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(requsts.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(requsts, user)
            return redirect('Matin')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(requsts, 'authentication/register.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear ,There is no template supplied.

if you want to use this view , write a template in the right path

see the doc [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

This is the actual view for your request url.

watch this in the doc above linked :

> It’s your responsibility to provide the html for the login template , called registration/login.html by default. This template gets passed four template context variables:

Answer (score 0):

**Check these things first:**

**Step-1:** Check that you have added the location of the template

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            . . . . 
            . . . .
    },
]
```

Your `template folders` should look like this way-

```
DjangoProject (Django project folder)
   |_DjangoProject
   |_accounts
   |_templates
                |_registration
                              |_login.html
```

**Step 2:** In your `views.py` file set template_name this way.
template_name = "registration/login.html"

Hope this works!